# jquery mobile transition link to the same page with href

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to accomplish this.  I have a page which gets loaded with selected:

```
    ....
        <div data-role="content" style="">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#departmentPage">Departments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    ....

<section id="departmentPage" data-role="page">

    <section data-role="panel" id="departmentPageMenu"  data-position="left" data-dismissible="false" data-display="overlay" style="">
        <header data-role="header" id="Header2" style="">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <a href="#pressReleasePageMenu" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c">Close</a>
        </header>

        <div data-role="content" style="">
            <ul data-role="listview">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>


    <header data-role="header" id="departmentPageHeader">

        <a style="" id="pressReleaseHome" href="#departmentPageMenu" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c">Home</a>
        <h2 style=" font-size: 18px;" id="pressReleaseTitle" >Departments</h2>

    </header>

    <div data-role="content" id="departmentPageContent" style="">

        <div  id="contentData" style="color: #262626; font-size: 16px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; ">
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: center;">
                <div style="" id="paginationContainer"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

which puts the link as:

http://localhost/MDefault.aspx#departmentPage

this page pulls a departments list that each is wrapped in an anchor
Ex. 
    [HR](http://localhost/MDefault.aspx?id=1)

But if I select this the page goes back to the initial page not the departmentsPage.  Ive tried modifying the link:

```
<a href="http://localhost/MDefault.aspx?id=1#departmentsPage">HR</a>
```

But nothing happens.  What is the best way to handle this so that the link goes back to the departmentsPage?